# Debugging error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net

### Introduction (Warning: Bad English)

Hello everybody. I need some help with my program.

So, basically my program is made for downloading one file and extracting it to known path, for example `C:\Users\ProfileName\Documents\Windward`. This path is suitable for most part of people. But for some people it's wrong path (Because file need's to be installed in `Documents\Windward` folder). So i decided to make changeable path. I thought I making everything right, but something gone wrong. And i thing something is frong with this: `Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text & "\Localization.zip"`, but i don't know how to fix it.

Please help me!

### Error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type System.InvalidOperationException occurred in AutoDownloadV2.exe

    Additional information: Error in form creating.  Exception.InnerException. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

### After Debug I recieve this:

```
in AutoDownloadV2.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in :string 190

in AutoDownloadV2.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() в B:\Projects\Progs\AutoDownloadV2\AutoDownloadV2\AutoDownloadV2\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:string 35

in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()

in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()

in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)

in AutoDownloadV2.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :string 81 The program '[5452] AutoDownloadV2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

### Here is my code (I have removed the useless part of code.)

```
Public Class Form1

Public WithEvents download As WebClient
Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text & "\Localization.zip"

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\Documents\Windward"
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False 
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        download = New WebClient
        download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://http://exsite.example"), path)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error! " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub download_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles download.DownloadProgressChanged
    Try
        Label3.Text = "Downloaded : " & e.BytesReceived / 1024 & " kb / " & e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024 & " kb  "
        Label4.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & "%"
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error! " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    If e.BytesReceived = e.TotalBytesToReceive Then
        Unzip()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Unzip()
    Dim startPath As String = path
    Dim zipPath As String = path
    Dim extractPath As String = ("C:\Users\" + SystemInformation.UserName + "\Documents\Windward\")
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(extractPath + "mods\translateMod\Localization.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(extractPath + "mods\translateMod\Localization.txt")
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(extractPath + "mods\translateMod\Version.txt")
        Catch e As Exception
        End Try
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
    Else
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(path)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initialization of path inside the Form1_Load after setting the initial value in TextBox1

```
Dim path As String 

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "C:\Users\" & SystemInformation.UserName & "\Documents\Windward"
    path = TextBox1.Text & "\Localization.zip"
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False 
End Sub
```

The problem is caused by the reference to TextBox1 in the global area of your form class. At that point the TextBox1 is still Nothing (not initialized) thus you get the NRE message (Null Reference Exception)

Comment: Thanks! Problem with launching is now fixed, but it cause another error (When i use button, that download file.). So i'll try to fix it by my self.
Thank you again!

Comment: So i tried to fix my second problem but every time i recive this:`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: call destination has created an exception`